# Error: No package 'cairo' found on ec2 bitnami MEAN server

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I am trying to setting my MEAN application on bitnami server. While installing dependencies I am facing below error. I followed all the instructions given in the error but unable to solve it.

No package 'cairo' found during installing nmp install canvas.

The error i am facing is following

*Package cairo was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `cairo.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'cairo' found*

I have set the environment variable on bitnami server by taking reference from bitnami documentation but  still getting same error.

But it is working fine in local system with same environment.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You need install `cairo` on ec2 instance before install `node-canvas`.

```
On newer versions of Amazon Linux (2015.03 and above) the following
command is sufficient to install node-canvas:

$ sudo yum install cairo-devel libjpeg-turbo-devel giflib-devel -y
```

https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/wiki/Installation---Amazon-Linux-AMI-(EC2)

or, if Ubuntu and other Debian based systems:

```
$ sudo apt-get update 
$ sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev libjpeg8-dev libpango1.0-dev libgif-dev build-essential g++
```

https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/wiki/Installation---Ubuntu-and-other-Debian-based-systems

If error with `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` will be repeated, you need to find where the `cairo.pc`:

```
$ dpkg-query -S cairo.pc    
libcairo2-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/cairo.pc
libpango1.0-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/pangocairo.pc
```

and manually add this path to `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` in file `/opt/bitnami/scripts/build-setenv.sh`

maybe you also need to add the path to `xproto.pc`:

```
$ dpkg-query -S xproto.pc
x11proto-core-dev: /usr/share/pkgconfig/xproto.pc
```

and add `-I/opt/bitnami/common/include/freetype2` to `CXXFLAGS`

As a result, `build-env.sh` looks like this: https://gist.github.com/bouriate/81ac44f63c0107f2c74f

P.S. You need logout/login from instance for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Thanks stdob. When i run "sudo yum install cairo-devel" command. I get message. There are no enabled repos.
Run "yum repolist all" to see the repos you have.
You can enable repos with yum-config-manager --enable <repo>